# How to filter an array which elements have a nested array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the logic to be able to filter an array that contains another array in a property. See below:

```
let filterValue = 'berries'; 

const products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        productName: 'Strawberry Basil',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png?v=1588713373',
        type: ['berry', 'citrusy', 'fancy'],
        price: 5.5,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        productName: 'Sour Blueberry',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/SourBlueBerry_Still_4K_Front-SourBlueberry.png?v=1588713584',
        type: ['all', 'sour', 'berry'],
        price: 4,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        productName: 'Blackberry Jam',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/BlackBerry_Jam_Still_4K_Front-BlackberryJam.png?v=1595035965',
        type: ['all', 'berry'],
        price: 10,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        productName: 'Orange Nectarine',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Orange_Nectarine_Still_4K_Front-OrangeNectarine.png?v=1588713522',
        type: ['all', 'Citrus', 'fancy', 'juicy'],
        price: 6,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        productName: 'Lemon Verbena',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Lemon_Verbena_Still_4K_Front-LemonVerbena.png?v=1588713474',
        type: ['all', 'Citrus', 'classic', 'floral'],
        price: 4.5,
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        productName: 'Extra Peach',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/ExtraPeach_Still_4K_Front-ExtraPeach.png?v=1588713411',
        type: ['Juicy'],
        price: 8.5,
    },
];
```

As you can see above, I want to filter the array and only show those products that contain the filter val inside the type. I have tried but my solution is really long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const filteredProducts = products.filter(p => p.type.includes(type));`

You can use `.filter` on the outer array and `.includes` on the inner array to do what you're looking for.

For the record, 'berries' never appears in any of the 'type' arrays, but 'berry' does

Comment: And you can also do the check for `all`. It would be `const filteredProducts = products.filter(p => p.type.includes( filterType ) || p.type.includes('all'));`

Comment: thanks! this was a sample of the array, not all the products! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.filter()` with `Array.prototype.some()` get the filtered result. The some() method returns true if at least one element in the array passes the test by the given callback function.

```js
const filterValue = 'berry';

const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    productName: 'Strawberry Basil',
    productImgURL:
      'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png?v=1588713373',
    type: ['berry', 'citrusy', 'fancy'],
    price: 5.5,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    productName: 'Sour Blueberry',
    productImgURL:
      'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/SourBlueBerry_Still_4K_Front-SourBlueberry.png?v=1588713584',
    type: ['all', 'sour', 'berry'],
    price: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    productName: 'Blackberry Jam',
    productImgURL:
      'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/BlackBerry_Jam_Still_4K_Front-BlackberryJam.png?v=1595035965',
    type: ['all', 'berry'],
    price: 10,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    productName: 'Orange Nectarine',
    productImgURL:
      'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Orange_Nectarine_Still_4K_Front-OrangeNectarine.png?v=1588713522',
    type: ['all', 'Citrus', 'fancy', 'juicy'],
    price: 6,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    productName: 'Lemon Verbena',
    productImgURL:
      'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Lemon_Verbena_Still_4K_Front-LemonVerbena.png?v=1588713474',
    type: ['all', 'Citrus', 'classic', 'floral'],
    price: 4.5,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    productName: 'Extra Peach',
    productImgURL:
      'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/ExtraPeach_Still_4K_Front-ExtraPeach.png?v=1588713411',
    type: ['Juicy'],
    price: 8.5,
  },
];

const ret = products.filter(({ type }) =>
  type.some((x) => x.toLowerCase() === filterValue.toLowerCase())
);
console.log(ret);
```